# How to implement 'URLSearchParams' and 'RequestOptions' when transforming from Angular 4 to Angular 7

Tags: angular

I am converting my project from Angular 4 to Angular 7. I have transferred http to httpClient and used common/http as well. Im new to Angular and I have no idea how to convert this UrlSearchParms and  RequestOptions to the new version. Can someone tell me how to convert the following to the angular 7? I know this may seems silly. But hope you can bear up and point me a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just omit the class and provide the options to your call. You should also change your RxJS operators to use `pipe` :

```
return this.http.get(environment.API_BASE_URL + '/' + apiUrl, {
  headers,
  search: params
}).pipe(
  .map(this.extractData),
  .catchError(this.handleError)
);
```

Comment: Can u please be kind to show me the whole complete conversion. Thank you soo much!

Comment: @OshanaDissanayake this is the whole, complete conversion. As I've told you, you don't need anymore classes, plain objects work. You don't need Request Options anymore, and you don't have URL search params in your code sample.

Answer (score 0):

In the Http Client you can achieve same thing in following way.

```
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }    

   getData(){
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers  = headers.append('header-1', 'value-1');
        headers  = headers.append('header-2', 'value-2');

       let params = new HttpParams();
       params = params.append('param-1', 'value-1');
       params = params.append('param-2', 'value-2');

       this.httpClient.get("/data", {headers , params })
   }
```

Here `HttpParams` and `HttpHeaders` are immutable classes so after each call set or append methods they return a new instance that's why you should do this : params = params.append(...)

Hope this will help!

Comment: yes in headers you can add RequestOptions, RequestOptionArgs, ResponseContentType by key value pair

Comment: I have see this solutions earlier! Tried it but cant take it to work! Can u please be kind to show me the whole complete conversion. Thank you soo much!